# Time Limit Exceeded for Merge k Sorted Lists(leetcode)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

[merge-k-sorted-lists](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/)

Merge k sorted linked lists and return it as one sorted list. Analyze and describe its complexity.

My code:

```
    ListNode *mergeTwoLists(ListNode *p1, ListNode *p2) {
    ListNode dummy(-1);
    ListNode *head = &dummy;
    while(p1 != nullptr && p2 != nullptr) {
        if (p1->val < p2->val) {
            head->next = p1;
            head = head->next;
            p1 = p1->next;
        } else {
            head->next = p2;
            head = head->next;
            p2 = p2->next;
        }
    }
    if (p1 != nullptr) {
        head->next = p1;
    }
    if (p2 != nullptr) {
        head->next = p2;
    }
    //head->next = nullptr;
    return dummy.next;
}
ListNode *mergeKLists(vector<ListNode *> &lists) {
    if (lists.size() == 0) return nullptr;
    if (lists.size() == 1) return lists[0];
    ListNode *p1, *p2, *p;
    while (lists.size() > 1) {
        p1 = lists.back();
        lists.pop_back();
        p2 = lists.back();
        lists.pop_back();
        p = mergeTwoLists(p1, p2);
        lists.push_back(p);
    }
    return lists[0];
}
```

I always get Time Limit Exceeded. How should i change the program?

Comment: this is a standard question you will get an answer just google it. Plus I suspect this is already asked on stackoverflow, so you can search here also. Still I have given the broad idea hope it helps.

Comment: @sasha Thank you. I chane my code by using `lists.insert(lists.begin(), p)`. I have searched before in the stackoverflow, maybe I am careless, and I will try to get out of that bad habit. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your are doing has complexity `O(nk^2)` where `n` is the size of each array. You merge two lists at a time. Why ? you merge first two lists it takes `2n` operations also the size of the first two combined is `2n`. Now you merge this with the third, the  array size becomes `3n` and `3n` operations are done, so total number of operations are `2n+3n+....kn` ( arithmetic progression ) which is `O(nk^2)`. Instead take a priority queue ( **min heap** ) insert first elements of all k lists. Now each time take the smallest element from priority queue ( put this in your new list ), remove it from the priority queue and insert the next element of the list to which this element belonged. As all elements are inserted and deleted from priority queue once and in total there are `nk` elements the complexity is `O(nklog(k))`. ( Time to delete / insert ) priority queue is `O(log(number_of_elements_in_queue))`. And in  the queue at maximum there are `k` elements at any time. 
For a more detailed explanation plus a code have a look here : [Merging k sorted lists](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays/). I assume this would be enough to get AC on leetcode :).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are doing unbalanced merges. If each list has n elements to start with and `merge(a,b)` means you merge lists of length `a` and `b` (which takes time `O(a+b)`), then the operations you are doing are

```
merge(n,n)
merge(2n,n)
merge(3n,n)
merge(4n,n)
....
```

and so you're paying a lot of cost iterating over the long list so many times; with `k` elements you're doing about `(1/2) k^2 n` work.

You could look for a specialized imbalance merging algorithm, but a much easier approach would be to just reorganize your work to merge lists of similar size. If you started with `k` lists each of `n` elements, then you would do

```
k/2 instances of `merge(n,n)`
k/4 instances of `merge(2n,2n)`
...
1 instance of `merge(nk/2, nk/2)`
```

Each step takes `nk` time, and there are `lg(k)` steps, for a total cost of `nk lg(k)`.

If `k` isn't a power of 2 or the lists are not all the same length, there are lots of things you can do to try and minimize the overall amount of work, but a very simple way is to make `lists` a `deque` instead of a `vector`, and for each merge you pop two lists of the back and push the result in the *front* instead of the *back*. Another simple optimization on this is to first sort the lists by length.

---

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28937208/1084944) is likely better when `k` is not too large. When `k` is rather large you're probably better off with a hybrid algorithm: you pick an appropriate `m` and you organize the total work as I've described, but rather than merging 2 lists at a time, you merge `m` lists at a time.

My first two guesses at an appropriate `m` are `ceil(sqrt(k))` and the largest value for which the other answer's algorithm is efficient for an `m`-way merge.

(if for some strange reason `m` is still very large, then you do the `m`-way merge with the hybrid algorithm)

---

Why do I make the predictions above? The other answer only makes one pass through the data, so as long as your CPU can efficiently maintain a priority queue of length `k` as well as read from `k` lists at the same time, it is surely better than my algorithm which makes many passes through the data.

But when `k` gets too large, you run into problems:

- Your TLB might not have enough entries to read from `k` lists at a time
- Your cache might not be big enough to store a cache line or two from all of `k` of the lists as well as fit a priority queue

cache misses and especially TLB misses will degrade performance. The hybrid algorithm reorganizes the work so that you keep the benefit of my algorithmic approach (balanced merges) while nearly all of the work is done with the efficient `m`-way merge from the other answer.